# Twitter Bootstrap and ASP.Net menu don't work with routing

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I Have and ASP.net menucontrol and all works good until I use Routing on the site.
I Have fixed the "hoverissue" with thte menucontrol so I have to click menuitems to show the subitems.
The problem is, as soon as I use routing and click the menu, it doesn't open subitems, it redirects me to http://www.xxx.com/RouteData/# (it only adds the # - sign).

My Site.master

```
                        <asp:Menu ID="mnuMainMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
                        IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal"
                        CssClass="navbar navbar-nav"
                        StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav"
                        StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"
                        DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu">
                        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="dropdown" Font-Underline="False" />
                        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
                        <LevelSubMenuStyles>
                            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="nav navbar-nav" Font-Underline="False" />
                        </LevelSubMenuStyles>
                    </asp:Menu>
```

My Site.master.cs

```
        private void GetMenuData()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string strCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        string sql = "select menu_id, menu_name, menu_parent_id, menu_url from tbl_Menu";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(table);
        DataView view = new DataView(table);
        view.RowFilter = "menu_parent_id is NULL";
        foreach (DataRowView row in view)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(row["menu_name"].ToString(),
            row["menu_id"].ToString());
            menuItem.NavigateUrl = row["menu_url"].ToString();
            mnuMainMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
            AddChildItems(table, menuItem);
        }

    }

    private void AddChildItems(DataTable table, MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        DataView viewItem = new DataView(table);
        viewItem.RowFilter = "menu_parent_id=" + menuItem.Value;
        foreach (DataRowView childView in viewItem)
        {
            MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem(childView["menu_name"].ToString(),
            childView["menu_id"].ToString());
            childItem.NavigateUrl = childView["menu_url"].ToString();
            menuItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
            AddChildItems(table, childItem);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone else have this problem and is there a solution for it?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Edit* SOLVED
As stupid as I am I actually found the problem.
When I added the script to include the jQuery and bootstrap .JS files I missed one ~

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jQuery-1.9.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(" /Scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
```

It's now corrected to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jQuery-1.9.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
```

and all works good.

Comment: Could you please provide piece of html markup for that menu?

Comment: Sorry, I Edited the post and added that.